# MAMP Vhosts Slow

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, virtualhost, mamp

Ever since I started using Vhosts with MAMP, page requests have been quite slow. It takes 3 to 5 seconds or more to process a page request. I'm wondering if it's the way my `hosts` or `vhosts` files are setup:

hosts:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost

255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

127.0.0.1 mysite.local www.mysite.local
127.0.0.1 anothersite.local www.anothersite.local
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.local
    ServerAlias www.mysite.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/username/Sites/mysite.local/
    <Directory /Users/username/Sites/mysite.local/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName anothersite.local
    ServerAlias www.anothersite.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/username/Sites/anothersite.local/
    <Directory /Users/username/Sites/anothersite.local/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Change your `ServerName`s to `example.dev` or something other than `.local`. Forgot the technical explanation but basically, `.local` is used by Bonjour.

Comment: I swear Apple used `.local` for mDNS and Bonjour *just* to make like difficult for companies with active directory and a `.local` TLD (which is almost all of them).

Comment: This was the fix!  I'm not sure what changed, but myhost.local _used to_ work just fine.  myhost.dev it is from now on.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `hosts` resolution process for things in `/etc/hosts/` is very, very fast, even if there are hundreds of host declarations in there. The name-service cache daemon keeps such lookups in memory as well, so they should be even faster.

The problem is most likely somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm troubleshooting this very same issue. I haven't figured it out entirely, but I have noticed that when I edit my /etc/hosts file, I have to enter my admin password (which I think is OSX's way of enabling sudo commands). For the next couple minutes my local testing sites are snappy. Then eventually they go back to being unbearably slow. I can fix it by adding a blank line to my /etc/hosts (because it makes me enter the password again) but it only lasts for a few minutes at a time.

I think this information is important to solving this issue, but I'm not sure how. Maybe someone else can help make sense of it.